# NPE after recreating an array

Tags: java, opengl

I'm trying to create an X by Y grid of squares that automatically expands when the edge is reached, however, I'm getting a null pointer exception whenever it attempts to render one of the new squares, it throws a null pointer exception, despite the previous line checking if the variable used it null or not.

It is likely something silly as i'm now going back to a writing something i started months ago, and have forgotten a lot since then.
Here's my code :

```
    public static void renderMapSquare(MapSquare sq)
{
    System.out.println("[MS] " + sq.y + " is sq null? " + (sq.color == null));

    Render.setColor(sq.color); //Null Pointer Here
    Render.Triangle(sq.a);

    Render.setColor(sq.color);
    Render.Triangle(sq.b);

    Render.setColor(sq.color);
    Render.Triangle(sq.c);

    Render.setColor(sq.color);
    Render.Triangle(sq.d);      

    Render.BorderMapSquare(sq);
}
```

ExtendMap method

```
    private void extendMapY(int extension)
{
    MapSquare[][] mapSquaresTemp = new MapSquare[mapSquares.length][mapSquares[0].length + extension];
    RTSLogging.log(this.getClass(), "Recreated mapsquares with x " + mapSquaresTemp.length + " y " + mapSquaresTemp[0].length);

    for (int i = 0; i < mapSquares.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapSquares[0].length; j++)
            mapSquaresTemp[i][j] = mapSquares[i][j];
    }
    System.out.println(mapSquares.length + " " + mapSquaresTemp.length);
    System.out.println(mapSquares[0].length + " " + mapSquaresTemp[0].length);

    for (int i = mapSquares.length -1; i < mapSquaresTemp.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = mapSquares[0].length -1; j < mapSquaresTemp[0].length; j++)
        {
            MapSquare temp = new MapSquare(i, j);
            mapSquaresTemp[i][j] = temp;

        }
    }

    BoundPY += extension;
    mapSquares = mapSquaresTemp;
}
```

draw method

```
    public void draw(int eyeX, int eyeY)
{
    for (int x = eyeX - 50; x <= eyeX + 50; x++)
    {
        for (int y = eyeY - 50; y <= eyeY + 50; y++)
        {
            if ((x < BoundNX || y < BoundNY))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if (x > BoundPX || y > BoundPY)
                {
                    RTSLogging.log(this.getClass(), "We hit a wall");                       
                    if (x > BoundPX)
                    {
                        this.extendMapX(100);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (y > BoundPY)
                    {
                        this.extendMapY(100);
                        break;
                    }

                }
                Render.renderMapSquare(mapSquares[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where and hao is `Render` defined and initialized?

Comment: Render is the class i use for all my rendering : renderMapSquare is a function in there

Comment: There are 2 possible reasons: `render is null` or `sq` is null. Can you check it please?

Comment: That what i thought, but it seems they all exist, as in )Render.class == null), (sq == null) and (sq.color == null) all return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extendMapY is wrong.

You extend an array of `x * y` elements to `x * (y + extension)`, but you don't initialize all the new elements.

It should be :

```
for (int i = 0; i < mapSquaresTemp.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = mapSquares[0].length; j < mapSquaresTemp[0].length; j++)
    {
        MapSquare temp = new MapSquare(i, j);
        mapSquaresTemp[i][j] = temp;

    }
}
```